# Storage of documents in our own databases

Tags: docusignapi

Does Docusign allow storage of documents in our own databases if we are integrating Docusign in our application ?I haven't tried anything as I was unable to find documentation regarding the same.

Comment: Welcome! ***Please accept accept (check) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0):

You can download completed envelopes using the following [API endpoint](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/get/) and then store it anywhere you like.
This endpoint allows you to download the whole envelope combined in a single PDF or download each document separately.

Another way to do it is to set **Agreement Actions** to move completed envelopes automatically to one of the predefined cloud storage providers.
[image]